# How would i get the time to be first and the date last but also include the timezone?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

Hi im trying to get my bot made with discord.py to have a good morning command and say the date and time but the date is first and the time is last but also its in military time and the year is first for the date how would i fix this? [Response from bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6qDA.png)

```py
@client.command(aliases=["gm"])
async def goodmorning(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(description= f"Good Morning, it is currently {ctx.message.created_at}", colour = 0x8bc1a9)
    
    discord.Embed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at

    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Message.created_at` is a `datetime.datetime` object, so you can use `datetime.datetime.strftime`, which will format the datetime as a string in a format you pass. You can find the formatting codes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

So, for example, if I wanted the datetime in the `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM` format, I would use:

```
formatted_datetime = ctx.message.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
embed = discord.Embed(description=f"Good Morning, it is currently {formatted_datetime}", colour=0x8bc1a9)
embed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

As a side note, `discord.Embed` is a reference to the `Embed` class, not your `Embed` object. So, to set the timestamp for your object, you'll want to use `embed.timestamp` as I did in the above example (as `embed` *is* a reference to your object).